# Getting Input Names from Frozen Tensorflow Estimator Graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If a graph's inputs are passed into placeholders:

`input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [...], name="inputs")`

The frozen graph having this `input_layer` will have an input node named "inputs". How will I know the name of the input node of a frozen Estimator graph? Is it the first layer in the model function? Is it the name of the dictionary key of of the features parameter of a model function?

When I printed the nodes of the graph def generated after freezing, I got this candidate input layer names:

```
# Generated by the numpy_input_fn
enqueue_input/random_shuffle_queue 
random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany/n
random_shuffle_queue_DequeueMany

# This is probably the input
inputs/shape
inputs

# More nodes here
...
```

**Update**

Here's the graph [image: huge-ass-graph.png]

**More updates**

I checked the guide in using a saved model with estimators and I came up with this code:

```
input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)
input_layer = graph.get_operation_by_name('input_layer').outputs[0]
input_shape = input_layer.get_shape().as_list()[1:]
run_params['input_shape'] = input_shape
feature_spec = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(input_shape, input_layer.dtype)}

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=_predict_model_fn,
                                   params=run_params,
                                   model_dir=checkpoint_dir)

def _serving_input_receiver_fn():
    return tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)()

exported_model_path = estimator.export_savedmodel(checkpoint_dir, _serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

However, when I run this, I encounter this error:

```
File "... my module", line ..., in ...
    exported_model_path = estimator.export_savedmodel(checkpoint_dir, _serving_inp
  File "...\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 598, in export_savedmodel
    serving_input_receiver.receiver_tensors_alternatives)
  File "...\tensorflow\python\estimator\export\export.py", line 199, in build_all_signature_defs
    '{}'.format(type(export_outputs)))
ValueError: export_outputs must be a dict and not<class 'NoneType'>
```

Here's the _predict_model_fn:

```
def _predict_model_fn(features, mode, params):
    features = features['x']

    # features are passed through layers
    features = _network_fn(features, mode, params)

    # the output layer
    outputs = _get_output(features, params["output_layer"], params["num_classes"])
    predictions = {
        "outputs": outputs
    }

    return _create_model_fn(mode, predictions=predictions)


def _create_model_fn(mode, predictions, loss=None, train_op=None, eval_metric_ops=None, training_hooks=None):
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                  predictions=predictions,
                                  loss=loss,
                                  train_op=train_op,
                                  eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
                                  training_hooks=training_hooks)
```

Apparently, one must provide the `export_output` argument in the `EstimatorSpec` to be returned whenever one decides to export their model. With that, the `_predict_model_fn` has this return statement and adding the argument to the `_create_model_fn`:

```
return _create_model_fn(mode, predictions=predictions,
                            export_outputs={
                                "outputs": tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(outputs)
                            })
```

Comment: Having a glance at the source and how the API is used, it doesn't look like `tf.estimator.Estimator` uses placeholders as such. You can still use the model with `feed_dict` passing any tensor in the graph to replace feed its value, but I don't think there is a reliable way of getting the right tensor to replace. One not-really-a-solution but possible workaround is to [visualize the frozen graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz) and see if you can make sense of it to determine what is the node where you need to inject values.

Comment: (I mean I think there is no reliable way of getting the input tensor from an estimator that has been directly frozen to a `GraphDef`; in [Using SavedModel with Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators) there is guidance on how to save a trained model and serve predictions using the SavedModel format)

Comment: I do know that `tf.estimator.Estimator` doesn't use placeholders. I just put them in as some sort of comparison on how to get the input tensor. Visualizing it on tensorboard seems like a good idea, I'll post the graph in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to tell which one is the input or output tensor from a graph.

You should use the [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators) functions. Part of it is to generate a signature of the model that says exactly which tensor is the input and which one is the output.

You can take the same model and export it with different signatures. For example one would take a protocol buffer and give you a probability back, and another would take a string and give you a space embedding.

Comment: @RocketPingu I suspect yo don't return anything when the model is called in predict mode. Maybe add the _predict_model_fn code to the question

Comment: I provided an `export_output` in the returned `EstimatorSpec` and it worked. I'll be updating my post with the code and be accepting this answer since it did lead me there.

Comment: Would the input_name be 'x' in the code I gave above?

Comment: @RocketPingu No, you specify `tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` in your serving input receiver. This will add a few steps to the graph to take a string input and parse it into features (including what will be used as x). I think the input will be 'input_example' or something similar.

Comment: So the input_name of the placeholder step added to the graph will be `input_example`?

Comment: I read the code of `tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` and apparently, it creates a placeholder named `input_example_tensor`. I guess it would be nice if we can change this name or have an idea that it is named this way.

Comment: I am serving the model in Android. I can feed the input values (which is an array of floats given that the input is an image) to the "input_layer". However, I encounter this error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expects arg[0] to be string but float is provided`.

Comment: Your input is supposed to be a tf.Example protocol buffer in string form.

Comment: It's working now. I simply builded a raw_input_receiver_fn instead of a parsing one. I'm just having a problem with the shapes but that is unrelated to the problem now. Thank you so much for your help :bd

Comment: Here's the problem now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911525/using-a-frozen-savedmodel-graph-in-android-causes-a-shape-issue