# Estimator.predict() has Shape Issues?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I can train and evalaute a Tensorflow Estimator model without any problems. When I do prediction, this error arises:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): output_shape has incorrect number of elements: 68 should be: 2
     [[Node: output = SparseToDense[T=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ToInt32, ToInt32_1, ToInt32_2, bidirectional_rnn/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/time)]]
```

All of the model functions use the same architecture:

```
def _train_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    features = _network_fn(features, mode, params)

    outputs = _get_output(features, params["output_layer"],
                          params["num_classes"])
    predictions = {
        "outputs": outputs
    }

    ... # loss initialization and whatnot

def _eval_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    features = _network_fn(features, mode, params)
    outputs = _get_output(features, params["output_layer"], params["num_classes"])
    predictions = {
        "outputs": outputs
    }

    ... # loss initialization and whatnot


def _predict_model_fn(features, mode, params):
    features = _network_fn(features, mode, params)
    outputs = _get_output(features, params["output_layer"], params["num_classes"])
    predictions = {
        "outputs": outputs
    }

    ...
```

Here's the predict code:

```
def predict(params, features, checkpoint_dir):
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=_predict_model_fn,
                                       params=params,
                                       model_dir=checkpoint_dir)
    predictions = estimator.predict(input_fn=_input_fn(features))
    for i, p in enumerate(predictions):
        print(i, p)
```

I also checked the shapes given every time the input passes a layer when training, and the same thing for predicting. They give the same shapes:

Training:

```
conv2d [1, 358, 358, 16]
max_pool2d [1, 179, 179, 16]
collapse_to_rnn_dims [1, 179, 2864]
birnn [1, 179, 64]
```

Prediction:

```
conv2d [1, 358, 358, 16]
max_pool2d [1, 179, 179, 16]
collapse_to_rnn_dims [1, 179, 2864]
birnn [1, 179, 64]
```

Here are the `SparseTensor`s I passed to `sparse_to_dense`:

Training:

```
SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:1", shape=(?,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:2", shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

Evaluation:

```
SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:1", shape=(?,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:2", shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

Prediction:

```
SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:1", shape=(?,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=Tensor("CTCBeamSearchDecoder:2", shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

Which are all pretty much the same.

Any reason why this is happening? Shouldn't the `_predict_model_fn` work given that it follows the same architecture as that of the other `model_fn`s?

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_task_type': 'worker', '_is_chief': True, '_service': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_model_dir': 'checkpoint\\model-20180419-150303', '_task_id': 0, '_evaluation_master': '', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x00000091F58B3080>, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_master': '', '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': None, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from checkpoint\model-20180419-150303\model.ckpt-1
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1361, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _run_fn
    target_list, status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: output_shape has incorrect number of elements: 68 should be: 2
     [[Node: output = SparseToDense[T=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ToInt32, ToInt32_1, ToInt32_2, bidirectional_rnn/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/time)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\train_ocr.py", line 42, in evaluate_model
    evaluate(architecture_params, images, labels, checkpoint_dir)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\tf\experiment_ops.py", line 82, in evaluate
    predict(params, features, checkpoint_dir)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\tf\experiment_ops.py", line 90, in predict
    for i, p in enumerate(predictions):
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 492, in predict
    preds_evaluated = mon_sess.run(predictions)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 546, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1022, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1113, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1098, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1170, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 950, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: output_shape has incorrect number of elements: 68 should be: 2
     [[Node: output = SparseToDense[T=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ToInt32, ToInt32_1, ToInt32_2, bidirectional_rnn/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/time)]]

Caused by op 'output', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 119, in _main
    return self._bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\train_ocr.py", line 42, in evaluate_model
    evaluate(architecture_params, images, labels, checkpoint_dir)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\tf\experiment_ops.py", line 82, in evaluate
    predict(params, features, checkpoint_dir)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\tf\experiment_ops.py", line 90, in predict
    for i, p in enumerate(predictions):
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 479, in predict
    features, None, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 793, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\tf\experiment_ops.py", line 217, in _predict_model_fn
    outputs = _get_output(features, params["output_layer"], params["num_classes"])
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\tf\experiment_ops.py", line 134, in _get_output
    return _sparse_to_dense(decoded, name="output")
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\tf\experiment_ops.py", line 38, in _sparse_to_dense
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\sparse_ops.py", line 791, in sparse_to_dense
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_sparse_ops.py", line 2401, in _sparse_to_dense
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\asus.11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): output_shape has incorrect number of elements: 68 should be: 2
     [[Node: output = SparseToDense[T=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ToInt32, ToInt32_1, ToInt32_2, bidirectional_rnn/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/time)]]
```

**Update**

I tried using the same architecture in a different training run, I encountered a different shap error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): output_shape has incorrect number of elements: 69 should be: 2
     [[Node: output = SparseToDense[T=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ToInt32, ToInt32_1, ToInt32_2, bidirectional_rnn/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/time)]]
```

Apparently, the problem seems to lie in the `ctc_beam_search_decoder`. Switching to `ctc_greedy_decoder` doesn't help either. Why is it doing this?

**More updates**

I have uploaded the reproducible example: https://github.com/selcouthlyBlue/ShapeErrorReproduce

Comment: Providing all traceback may be helpful.

Comment: Added the stacktrace

Comment: In the traceback, it looks like "C:\Users\asus.11\Documents\Optimized_OCR\trainer\backend\train_ocr.py" is your code and the `evaluate_model` in it is also involved in this problem. Are you sure your evaluation is fine? Your evaluation seems to mingle with prediction. I'm confused and not sure how this is related to the code you presented. Hopefully some experts can come and help you. Good luck!

Comment: In `evaluate_model`, I call the prediction after running evaluation. The evaluation runs fine but the prediction does not.

Comment: I updated the problem such that I used a simpler network (with lesser layers). The problem seems to be on the `sparse_to_dense` part. I'll try printing the shape before it is fed to that part.

Comment: I have uploaded the reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the error. The problem actually lies in the way I used sparse_to_dense. Apparently, the order I gave is wrong where the values came first before the shape:

```
return tf.sparse_to_dense(tf.to_int32(decoded[0].indices),
                              tf.to_int32(decoded[0].values),
                              tf.to_int32(decoded[0].dense_shape),
                              name="output")
```

The order should be (shape comes first before values):

```
return tf.sparse_to_dense(tf.to_int32(decoded[0].indices),
                              tf.to_int32(decoded[0].dense_shape),
                              tf.to_int32(decoded[0].values),
                              name="output")
```